# Fast reports - currency format datafield

Tags: delphi, fastreport

I have a database field which is currency type. However, Fast Reports 4,13 does not display it as a currency type. How can I make it show currency (Euro with 2 decimals ?
I tried FormatStr=$ ###0.00 but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Did you try `DisplayFormat.FormatStr:=%2.2m; DisplayFormat.Kind:=fkNumeric` ?

Comment: Yes I did but it but it still does not work.

Comment: What did you get with %2.2. Are you using a non european system? If your field is recognized as a numeric field at least `#,##0.00 €` should work.

Comment: Tried #,##0.00 € but no avail. System is european.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one I found out by accident (after some conversation with Fast reports support) :
Just double click the component and paste inside the adequate format. see the picture :
[image]

Then it works. Pasting the same sting in the object inspector property of the field does not. Why not,I do not know...